# Want to press +,-,*,/for arithmetic operation using select case statement in vb.net but the output is wrong choice

Tags: vb.net, select, vb.net-2010

As I press + button it adds the numbers and as if I press - it subtracts the number but as I press + or - it is giving wrong choice output.

```
Imports System
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim a,b,c As Integer
        Dim d As String
        System.Console.WriteLine("Enter value of a and b")
        a=Val(System.Console.ReadLine())
        b=Val(System.Console.ReadLine())
        System.Console.WriteLine(" Press +,-,*,/ for opeartion")
        d=Val(System.Console.ReadLine())
        Select Case d
            Case "+"
                c=a+b
                System.Console.WriteLine(c)
            Case "-"
                c=a-b
                System.Console.WriteLine(c)
            Case "*"
                c=a*b
                System.Console.WriteLine(c)
            Case "/"
                c=a/b
                System.Console.WriteLine(c)
            Case Else
                MsgBox("wrong choice")
        End Select
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: What is the question? What goes wrong? What did you expect to happen, and what does happen instead? Haven you tried debugging? What came out of that? And also, you should format your code. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: the question is as i press + button it add the numbers and as if i press - it subtract the number but as i press + or - it is giving wrong choice output

Comment: That leaves the other questions...  What goes wrong? What did you expect to happen, and what does happen instead? Haven you tried debugging? What came out of that? Have you tried to determine, for instance, what the value of `d` actually is?

Comment: the vale of d is +,-,*,/ as i press + the value of a and b added and the result came out in c

Comment: but now the problem is solved

Comment: the problem is in d=Val(System.Console.ReadLine()) actually the value is stored as d=System.Console.ReadLine()

Comment: so finally the program now runs as i wanted to run

Comment: thanks for your help @MrLister